# How can I solve this problem in vs code (ipynb)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, runtime-error, ipython

```
import os 

image, label = load(os.path.join(PATH, 'train/cat/cat.100.jpg'), 0)
# casting to int for matplotlib to show the image
plt.figure()
plt.title(label)
plt.imshow(image/255.0)
plt.show()
```

When I run this, there is no error. But it shows as indefinitely in progress.
[image]

Comment: have you tried using skimage, PIL or opencv ?

Comment: yes. I already used skimage, PIL. It can work, but this way was also working.
So I think another problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
PATH = "/Users/reblochonMasque/Documents/Drawings/"
Image(filename = PATH + "My_picture.jpg", width=100, height=100)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Happy coding!